# Comunicação entre Python e Java

Tags: java, python

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação client servidor onde o servidor será escrito em python e o cliente em Java. O problema é que quando envia uma mensagem de Java para Python o servidor python recebe, mais o contrário não acontece. Aparentemente o servidor envia os bytes mas o cliente fica esperando infinitamente, indicando que não recebeu nada.

Código Python

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000

udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
origem = (HOST,PORT)
udp.bind(origem)
msg, client = udp.recvfrom(1000)
print(client," - ",msg)
msg = "recebido"
dest = ('192.168.1.4',5000)
echo = "resposta"
udp.sendto(echo.encode('ascii'),dest)
udp.close()
```

Código Java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String msg = "conectado";
        byte[] buffer = msg.getBytes();

        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            //Enviando pacote
            DatagramPacket pacote = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.4"), 5000);
            socket.send(pacote);

            //Receebendo pacote
            buffer = new byte[1000];
            pacote.setData(buffer);
            pacote.setLength(1000);
            socket.receive(pacote);

            //Convertendo arraybyte para String
            String conteudo = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println(conteudo);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: UDP não garante a entrega do pacote, talvez ele chegue ou não, entendeu?

Comment: Eu testei com TCP também e o resultado é o mesmo. O teste está sendo feito com o servidor e o cliente rodando na mesma máquina (localhost). Também fiz o teste usando o Matlab e também não funcionou. O Matlab consegue enviar mas não recebe. Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Eu tenho certeza que possa ser o firewall.

Comment: O seu firewall esta bloqueando o fluxo de entrada(InBound).

Comment: Desativei o firewall e problema persiste. Penso que seja incompatibilidade de tipo de dados, isto é, o array de byte do python não é a mesma coisa que o array de byte do java. Não sei como verificar esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Eu testei aqui e funcionou normal.Byte e a mesma coisa em qualquer linguagem, a única coisa que muda e a ordem dos bytes, mas isso e só se você executar de maquinas que tem arquiteturas diferentes.

Comment: voce precisa mesmo para sua aplicação implementar a comunicação em nível de socket?  Existe um motivo pelo qual criaram protocolos que abstraem o socket, como http, ftp, websocket, jsonrpc, etc...

Comment: Você está usando a mesma porta para os dois códigos, talvez seja esse o problema, tente mudar as portas para 5000 e 5001